# Laravel gif not working on LEMP server

Tags: laravel, gif

Can someone explain why gif is working on local development (using laravel with Valet) but it is not displayed when project is deployed on LEMP server. Gif is stored under storage/app/public on server this directory is with chmod -R 777. setTimeout is working fine and text is displayed only background gif is missing from loader div. My code in blade template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loading(){
            $('body').append('<div class="loader"></div>');
            info();
        }
    }
    function info(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.loader').append('<div class=info>XXX</div>');
        }, 2000);
    }
</script>

<style>
    .loader {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
        background: url('page-loader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 24px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Have you checked your server configuration? Ensure whether your server is serving the file correctly.

Comment: I am very new to this..I don`t know how to do it. I am following this guide http://devmarketer.io/learn/deploy-laravel-5-app-lemp-stack-ubuntu-nginx/ to configure nginx. Can you explain please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update - I found that you have to run "php artisan storage:link" command to link storage to public folder in laravel to get access to files in storage

Answer (score 0):

Edit your server configuration located at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`. Now add the following block to enable your server to start serving images and other static files.

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {   
  # Set expiry time for static content
  expires 1d;   
  # Set the Cache Control header 
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

Comment: Still no luck.. here is the file:

server {

listen 80 default_server; 
listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /var/www/konvertori/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name konvertori;

location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
      include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
     deny all;
}

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
     expires 1d;
     add_header Cache-Control "public";
     }
}

Answer (score 0):

Modified the nginx default file as suggested above. Still was not working but then I changed gif location from storage/app/public to /public where is the index file, now it works.